# Are there any helpful php form mail tutorials or php alternatives

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I am new to web development and php. I created a php script to use for my contact form on my webpage. The webpage is published and live but when filling out the contact form that the php is linked to I am not receiving the email.

When I click the submit button i am taken to a 404 page although my contact form is linked to a php script that I am not sure if I configured correctly. After submission the user should be directed to a thank you page

The information I need emailed is very simple is there a simpler way to receive the information from the contact form to my email, because I was not able to get the php script or the contact form to work properly?

```
<form action="contactform.php" method="post" id="contactform">
    <p>  <input type="Name" required placeholder="Name"> </p>
    <p>  <input type="email" required form="contactform" placeholder="Email"> </p>
    <p>  <input type="tel" required placeholder="Telephone"> </p>
    <p>  <textarea required class="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea> </p>
    <p> <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: where is php? i didn't see it?

Comment: I was unable to attach the full code. I've edited the question and added a portion of the code

Comment: none of your input contains name attribute so how's you get values in$_POST

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? What should go there instead?

Comment: @Jalen - for you to send information from a form to a PHP script, you need to give the inputs a name attribute, and yours don't have this. It should be something like `<input type="Name" required placeholder="Name" name="name">` - the `name=` part gives the name that you can use to access it, in this case, `$_POST['name']`

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I have added names to all the input fields

Comment: I am still not receiving the information though